# How to get the items selected in a dropdowncheckbox in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have a code that gives me the item selected in a dropdownlist but I can´t make it work for a dropdowncheckbox. In the following:

var Activity= document.getElementById("Cbo_ActivityTypes").value

var  Brand = document.getElementById("Cbo_Brand").value

Alert (Activity)

Alert (Brand)

Alert (activity) shows a window with the ID of the item selected, but the Alert(Brand) shows a windows saying undefined. It doesn't recognize that there were items selected in the field Brand.

Codes that load each box:

asp:DropDownList ID="Cbo_ActivityType" runat="server" Width="143px" AutoPostBack="True">

asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="Cbo_Brand" runat="server"  Width="180px" UseSelectAllNode="False">

Anyone can give some help on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is an asp webControl. So to get your Id in html use `'<%=ID.ClientID%>'`

```
var Activity= document.getElementById("<%=Cbo_ActivityTypes.ClientID%>").value

var Brand = document.getElementById("<%=Cbo_Brand.ClientID%>").value
```